# Optimization flags cause incorrect computation

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I am having a weird optimisation-only bug so I am trying to determine which flag is causing it. The error (incorrect computation) occurs with `-O1`, but not with `-O0`. Therefore, I thought I could use all of the `-f flags` that `-O1 includes to narrow down the culprit`. However, when I try that (using this list http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html), it works fine again!

Can anyone explain this, or give other suggestions of what to look for? I've run the code through `valgrind`, and it does not report any errors.

#### EDIT

I found that the computation is correct with `-O0`, incorrect with `-O1`, but correct again with `-O1 -ffloat-store`. Any thoughts of what to look for that would cause it not to work without `-ffloat-store`?

#### EDIT2

If I compile with my normal release flags, there is a computation error. However, if I add either:

```
-ffloat-store
```

or

```
-mpc64
```

to the list of flags, the error goes away.

Can anyone suggest a way to track down the line at which this flag is making a difference so I could potentially change it instead of requiring everyone using the code to compile with an additional flag?

Comment: *scratchin beard* well, on top of the noted "computed gotos" that are mentioned in your list, I dont nothing about giving in that behavoiur. But... I had an issue once where the release/o2 build crashed because of a missing semicolon on the end of a macro call (that magicly did not happen on o0 and debug)

Comment: There mush be `-o2` and `-o3` too.

Comment: Could you give us a minimal complete example?

Comment: The -ON flags also enable optimizations that don't have any flags associated with them.

Comment: @NikosC. is there a way to enable them individually? It seems like a good strategy to figure out WHICH optimization is causing the problem, so I can look for that explicitly?

Beta - Sorry, this is in a huge library and I can't reproduce it in any small case.

Comment: @DavidDoria Since they don't have any flags associated with them, you can't enable them individually.

Comment: @NikosC. I found that the computation is correct with -O0, incorrect with -O1, but correct again with -O1 -ffloat-store. Any thoughts of what to look for that would cause it not to work without -ffloat-store ?

Comment: @DavidDoria Hm, looks like you have numerically unstable FP operations somewhere. You might be comparing doubles with too small an epsilon perhaps? Try a larger value for your epsilon.

Answer (score 3):

From back in my GCC/C++ days the optimization bug like this that I remember was that with `-O0` on methods where no return value was specified would return the last value of that type in the method (probably what you wanted to return right?) whereas with optimisations on it returned the default value for the type, not the last value of the type in the method (this might only be true for value types, I can't remember). This would mean you would develop for ages with the debug flags on and everything would look fine, then it would stop working when you optimised.

For me not specifying a return value is a compilation error, but that was C++ back then.

The solution to this was to switch on the strongest set of warnings and then to treat all warnings as errors: that will highlight things like this. (If you are not already doing this then you are in for a whole load of pain!)

If you already have all of the errors / warnings on then the only other option is that a method call with side-effects is being optimised out. That is going to be harder to track down.

Comment: These kinds of issues have undefined behavior written all over them. Upping the warning level is your best chance at catching these.

Comment: @rubenvb - I am using -Wall , what should I be using?

Comment: @DavidDoria I use `-std=c++11 -pedantic -Wextra -Wconversion -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wmissing-include-dirs -Wstrict-aliasing`. It doesn't catch everything unfortunately, as some UB is by definition only detectable at runtime.

Comment: @rubenvb I compiled with those flags and nothing jumps out at me. This has driven me crazy for about a year, and now I finally have time to look into it, but don't know what to do haha.

Comment: Have you tried Clang as well? The manual doesn't list all the differences between global optimization options. You should be able to see the backend invocation by adding "-v" to you command, which might reveal more guts.

Comment: @rubenvb I found that the computation is correct with -O0, incorrect with -O1, but correct again with -O1 -ffloat-store. Any thoughts of what to look for that would cause it not to work without -ffloat-store ?

Comment: @DavidDoria: Do you rely on floating point equality somewhere?

Comment: You're going to have to specify "incorrect". I was assuming a large numerical error, this might just be float rounding going on, or a 80-bit float stored in a 64-bit double (which is completely legal btw).

Comment: @DavidDoria When you say incorrect I was assuming you meant something coming out as 0 (i.e. obviously wrong) rather than a value, but it sounds more subtle than that. Can you clarify?

Comment: @TheMouthofaCow It is definitely much more subtle. I actually can't even figure out why there is a problem - it is a line/triangle intersection, but the intersection in the demo is very far away from the edges of the triangle. Using "printf debugging" I was unable to see any values change from debug to release modes.

Comment: @rubenvb I would also imagine it is some kind of float precision/rounding problem, but am confused as to why it would not behave the same in -O0 as in -O1. I don't suppose there are warning flags to check for float comparisons (of which I didn't see any, but could have missed them). Or other things that could be going weird with float rounding, etc.?

Comment: @DavidDoria right, that sounds like the sort of computation that has the capacity to be unstable. You got any unit tests?

Comment: @TheMouthofaCow - Yep. They all pass :) (probably just bad tests haha). This is also a unit test for the full line/triangle intersection. That is why I am so interested in why it is failing.

Comment: @DavidDoria I've been there and it's painful (not sure I would ever want to go back to C++, although it might be my only way out of writing corporate arseware!). It sounds like you are already doing what I would do: print the output of all of the intermediate function calls to the console at some point the two versions are going to differ, my guess would be that at that point something slightly dodgy is going on.